# Is there such a thing as the "Tamper Data firefox plugin" for chrome?

Tags: security, firefox, testing, google-chrome

I can't find anything that is remotely similar to this. Is there a limitation in chrome/webkit that makes it impossible ?

[Tamper Data Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)

Answer (score 3):

No and there won't be any time soon because Chrome's add-on api is more restrictive than firefox.  However you can use [Burp](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) which is better in every way.  Most importantly Less bugs,  more features,  more compatible with strange post formats.

Comment: [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is another excellent proxy tool.

Comment: If it comes down to a proxy. Charlesproxy is awesome.

Comment: Both Burp and Charles-proxy are Java, so should be cross-platform.

OP doesn't mention what he wants to do.  As discussed at the link Neil mentioned above, certain monitoring options are built into Chrome.